# C# Socket Programming: Combining server and client into 1 solution

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets

Currently im working on a facilitator application, competitor application and a chat server. Im using C# socket programming with winform.

It is to run 1 facilitator application and multiple competitor application connected to each other through the server.

Is there a way i can combine the server codes into the facilitator solution so that when i just run the facilitator the server is also launched together with the facilitator app.

Currently what im doing is to make the server into a .exe then then i run my facilitator application, it will alsp start the server.exe to launch the server.

```
public Facilitator()
    {
        Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Guest\Desktop\Server.exe");
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

But just wondering if it is possible to incorporate it into just the facilitator app.

I referenced my chat server from this [C# chat server guide](http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-chat-server-programming.htm) and did my app based on this.

Your help will be appreciated.
My apologies for my language if its a bit difficult to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you want to debug both at the same time you can do this in Visual Studio like this.

Put the the client in one project and the server in another. Put both projects in the same solution. Right click on the solution name, pick "Set startup projects". Pick both projects and they will both start when you start debugging.

Comment: Thanks a lot! now its able to start both. Just another question, is it possible to run the server but not show the console? thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is far better to keep libraries and executables in separate solutions simply to enforce separation. In this case, your server has a different purpose than the facilitator. Keep those separate - they have different concerns.

In addition, since your facilitator depends on the server to function properly, I would move the start process to the Main method in your `Program` class. Ensure it is running then start facilitator.